# Avoid jumping into C++ STL code in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I'm currently debugging a project I'm working on using Objective-C and C++ code.

The problem I'm encountering is that Xcode always steps into the C++ STL code whenever I am trying to step over a line that contains STL container calls of some kind.

This is really annoying! It takes me 4 "Step Over"s to get past this line for example:

```
medianVec.assign(greenPlane[0], greenPlane[(width*height)-1]);
```

I also don't see the point why Xcode is doing this.
Can't imagine that the info is of so much use for most developers.

Would appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance,

Flo

Comment: Are you sure you are pressing step over and not step into. This does not happen for me.

Comment: I definitely am. Just found out that this doesn't happen when I'm using LLVM GCC 4.2. The problem is that the new Obj-C syntax (like @{dictionaryKey:dictionaryValue}) is not working in this case. Any suggestions?